# How to generate a DSA key pair using OpenSSL libcrypto?

Tags: c, openssl, dsa

I have the following code trying to generate a DSA key pair.

```
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
ctx=EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(EVP_PKEY_DSA,NULL); EVP_PKEY_keygen_init(ctx);
if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_dsa_paramgen_bits(ctx,1024)<=0)      ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
```

and I get the following error

> 3073906944:error:06089094:digital envelope
>   routines:EVP_PKEY_CTX_ctrl:invalid operation:pmeth_lib.c:398:

Any clue on what I am doing wrong? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need **two** contexts; one for the params, and one for the actual keygen. You should do the following *two* sets of operations :

**Parameter Generation**

1. Create a param generator using `EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(EVP_PKEY_DSA, NULL)`
2. Set the bits in the param generator context using `EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_dsa_paramgen_bits`; **not** the keygen context (which, if you'r'e doing this right, doesn't even exist yet).
3. Initialize the param generator using `EVP_PKEY_paramgen_init`
4. Finally, generate the parameters using `EVP_PKEY_paramgen`. The result is a `EVP_PKEY` object (I'll call it `pkey_params`) that contains the input parameters for the upcoming key generation

Once the above is done, *then* you move on to the actual key generation, which is considerably simpler:

**Key Generation**

1. Create a new context using `EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(pkey_params, NULL)` Note the `pkey_params` is from the prior series of steps.
2. Initialize the generator context using `EVP_PKEY_keygen_init`
3. Generate the actual key using `EVP_PKEY_keygen`

Once done, all resources except the final `pkey` from above should be properly destroyed. Free the final key once done using it. That's it.

**Example**

This has no error checking whatsoever, but the order of operations is what is important here. So pay attention to that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/dsa.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>

// required for any BIO standard stream IO.
#include <openssl/applink.c>

int main()
{
    OPENSSL_init();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    // build parameters first
    EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx_params = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(EVP_PKEY_DSA, NULL);
    EVP_PKEY_paramgen_init(ctx_params);
    EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_dsa_paramgen_bits(ctx_params, 1024);

    EVP_PKEY* pkey_params = NULL;
    EVP_PKEY_paramgen(ctx_params, &pkey_params);

    // using parameters, build DSA keypair
    EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(pkey_params, NULL);
    EVP_PKEY_keygen_init(ctx);
    
    EVP_PKEY* pkey = NULL;
    EVP_PKEY_keygen(ctx, &pkey);

    // cleanup everything but the final key
    EVP_PKEY_free(pkey_params);
    EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(ctx_params);
    EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(ctx);

    // TODO: whatever you want with the generator pkey. in this
    //  example we're just dumping the full unencrypted key to 
    //  stdout. 
    DSA* dsa = EVP_PKEY_get1_DSA(pkey);
    BIO* bio = BIO_new_fp(stdout, BIO_NOCLOSE);
    PEM_write_bio_DSAPrivateKey(bio, dsa, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    BIO_flush(bio);
    DSA_free(dsa);
    EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output** (varies, obviously)

```
-----BEGIN DSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END DSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: You need to call EVP_PKEY_paramgen_init(ctx_params) *before* you do EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_dsa_paramgen_bits(ctx_params, 1024);
Otherwise EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_dsa_paramgen_bits returns an error (-1) and the key length will remain at the default of 2048 bits. The code above is lacking any error handling and can thus easily miss such problems.